# Facebook video thumbnail and video player

Tags: php, facebook, video

I want to make a video gallery with a video player similar to one Facebook uses.

After clicking on the video thumbnail, it should become large and play the video, just like Facebook's video player.

Comment: Voting to move to webmasters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed the video: Here is html example

```
<object width="400" height="224" >
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/10150262900042822" />
    <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/your-video-id" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="224">
    </embed>
</object>
```